# BSOD after enabling Hyper-V

Tags: windows-10, virtualization, bsod, hyper-v

I get a BSOD with stop code:

> SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED

on a clean windows install after enabling hyper-v.

The first time this has happened to me is when I installed docker for windows, which suggested that I enable Hyper-V. I selected ok, and then the laptop rebooted, and since then it didn't boot, giving out the same stopcode I mentioned.

I've reinstalled windows 10 and manually enabled Hyper-v, and ditto.
I've reinstalled one more time, and again, ditto.

I've searched and read some posts online, but I have yet to come across a post that actually mentions a concrete fix on this issue -- I'm clueless right now.

- I'm running Windows 10 Pro, and I have a separate physical drive that has Debian installed.
- My laptop is LG Gram 2018 (15Z980) with i7-8550u.
- I have the latest BIOS (2018-01-09)
- I don't see a virtualization option in my BIOS.
- `systeminfo` command says that my laptop is capable of running Hyper-V.

Edit:

- Virtualization is enabled, despite the lack of an option at the bios. Running docker toolbox (virtualbox) or running kvm from debian gives me no problem.
- I have checked the drivers and they were all up to date.
- I am going to check with LG support to see if this is an issue specific to my laptop, or to this model.

Comment: You have to enable virtualization settings in the BIOS. I’m pretty sure this is the cause of the problem. You’ll have to keep looking.

Comment: A lot of times it comes down to a buggy driver or the BIOS virtualization implementation.  You may want to try rolling back a version of the BIOS.  Also, verify that all your drivers are up to date.

Comment: If you are unable to enable VT-v within the firmware then you cannot use Hyper-V this also means you cannot use Docker.

Comment: [analyze the crash dump with windbg](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

15z980 BIOS has updated to K2ZC0250.
You can update using LG DNA Center application.
I just update that and Hyper-v Works Fine.

Comment: Unfortunately I still have the same problem after updating the firmware.

Comment: I did have the same bsod after enabling Hyper-V. After a few unsuccessful automatic recovery attempts I was able to boot into safe mode. I actually didn't do anything except for backing up files -- but after that my laptop booted up just fine and I have Hyper-V enabled. How strange.

Answer (score -2):

If you enable VT -x via BIOS you need to disable Hyper V. if still caused BSOD you need to disable Core Isolation. please go to https://www.teknokia.com/2019/09/how-to-fix-bsod-vt-x-virtualization-run-an-android-emulator-on-windows-10.html to disable it.

Comment: The author specifically is asking how to enable Hyper-V.  An answer indicating they should keep it disabled is absolutely unhelpful

Answer (score -3):

The issue can be resolved by updating drivers through Windows Update.

Comment: You may want to improve your answer by adding more details.